# Problem in strong tag when Parsing Html in swift 5

Tags: html, swift, parsing, nsstring

Hi i have a problem when im parsing a Html to NSAtributtedString in a UILabel.
The problem is in the strong text, the result is too bold (I guess when parsing the font is changed to "GibsonBold" and I need GibsonSemibold, or even change from Regular to Medium. I tried change tag to < b > or implement an style, but the result is always the same. Also I tried several extensions but I came out whit the same result.

This is the html String:

```
"<p>First text <strong> this text should be at lest Semibold</strong>. Final text.</p>"
```

Im using this two extension to parsing:

```
extension UIColor {
    var hexString:String? {
        if let components = self.cgColor.components {
            let r = components[0]
            let g = components[1]
            let b = components[2]
            return  String(format: "%02X%02X%02X", (Int)(r * 255), (Int)(g * 255), (Int)(b * 255))
        }
        return nil
    }
}

extension String {
    var html2Attributed: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            guard let data = data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
                return nil
            }
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    var htmlAttributed: (NSAttributedString?, NSDictionary?) {
        do {
            guard let data = data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
                return (nil, nil)
            }

            var dict:NSDictionary?
            dict = NSMutableDictionary()

            return try (NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: &dict), dict)
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
            return (nil, nil)
        }
    }
    
    func htmlAttributed(using font: UIFont, color: UIColor, lineHeight: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            let htmlCSSString = "<style>" +
                "html *" +
                "{" +
                "font-size: \(font.pointSize * 0.75)pt !important;" +
                "color: #\(color.hexString!) !important;" +
                "font-family: \(font.familyName), Helvetica !important;" +
                "line-height: \(lineHeight * 0.06) !important;" +
                "}</style> \(self)"

            guard let data = htmlCSSString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
                return nil
            }

            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And the implementation in label:

```
descriptionLabelText.attributedText = description.htmlAttributed(using: UIFont.gibsonRegular.withAdjustedSize(16),
                                                                    color: .greyscale800,
                                                                    lineHeight: 20.adjusted)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently all the css styling only defines the font to use and the font size, not really the `style` (bold, italic, regular etc) or the `weights` (normal, bold, light etc) so these tags pick up the default styles of the  tag.

I created the following HTML

```
let htmlString
            = "<p>Normal text <strong> Strong set to 600 font weight </strong>. <b> Bold set to italic style </b>"
```

And then I use your code like this

```
label.attributedText = htmlString.htmlAttributed(using: UIFont(name: "Gibson-Regular",
                                                               size: 16)!,
                                                 color: .red,
                                                 lineHeight: 20)
```

This gives me the following result as you probably see now

[image: HTML Text iOS Swift html Attributed text label custom style and font]

If you added all the fonts (Gibson regular, bold, italic) to your file system properly, you can add specific styles in your CSS.

Small changes to your `func htmlAttributed`

```
func htmlAttributed(using font: UIFont,
                    color: UIColor,
                    lineHeight: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString? {
    do {
        let htmlCSSString = "<style>" +
            "html *" +
            "{" +
            "font-size: \(font.pointSize * 0.75)pt !important;" +
            "color: #\(color.hexString!) !important;" +
            "font-family: \(font.familyName), Helvetica !important;" +
            "line-height: \(lineHeight * 0.06) !important;" +
            "}" +
            
            // customize bold
            "b" +
            "{" +
            "font-size: \(font.pointSize * 0.75)pt !important;" +
            "font-style: italic;" + // I set bold to be italic
            "font-family: \(font.familyName), Helvetica !important;" +
            "line-height: \(lineHeight * 0.06) !important;" +
            "}" +
            
            // customize strong font weight
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight
            "strong" +
            "{" +
            "font-size: \(font.pointSize * 0.75)pt !important;" +
            "font-weight: 600;" + // customize weight to what you want
            "font-family: \(font.familyName), Helvetica !important;" +
            "line-height: \(lineHeight * 0.06) !important;" +
            "}" +
            
            "}</style> \(self)"
        
        guard let data = htmlCSSString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                      options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                      documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        print("error: ", error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

With this change you will see some changes to the weight of the `strong` tag and I made the `b` tag render as italics

[image: HTML attributed UILabel set font font size font style strong tag bold tag swift iOS]

Finally, as far as I know, you cannot set the weight to `Semi Bold` so if you want to use the `Semi Bold` font, you have explicitly set this as the font you want to use.

So you can customize the strong tag:

```swift
// I set font family to Gibson italic for example
// You can set it to semi bold font
"strong" +
"{" +
"font-size: \(font.pointSize * 0.75)pt !important;" +
"font-family: \(UIFont(name: "Gibson-Italic", size: 16)!), Helvetica !important;" +
"line-height: \(lineHeight * 0.06) !important;" +
"}" +
```

[image: Html to NSAtributtedString in a UILabel custom style strong bold font iOS swift]

I think this should give you some ideas on how to customize to suit your solution

Comment: Hi, I try this but nothing happens. The final output text sill the same. This seems the right answer but I can't figured out what's wrong

Comment: If you can share your updated code or put a minimal reproducible example on a github repo and I will try to debug it at my end

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: My bad, I double check my code and I forgotten something and now its works really fine! Thanks